# Change docker dns option on docker-compose

Tags: dns, docker, docker-swarm

Problem: My container not find others hosts outside the swarm if ndots=0 on resolv.conf .I did some tests and if a remove or change ndots to 1 works.

There's some way to delete or change the option ndots on docker-compose or in my docker network ?

Answer (score 0):

the network inside the container is different than the one on the host computer so you may use a bashscript to change resolv.conf inside the container or just use your host network as the containers network with `--net=host` flag

```bsh
docker run -it --net=hos -p 8080:8080 containerName
```

the flag above uses host computer network so you have to use same ports inside and outside of container